# Fetching data from Linking Table in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am brand new to Hibernate and have yet to wrap my head around some of the more complex queries which are possible. So I have a super simple database schema:
[image: Database Schema]

and then I have Hibernate mappings for User, List, and Task as follows:

User:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.brennydoogles.User" table="user">
        <id name="userID" column="UserID"/>
        <property name="userName" column="UserName"/>
        <property name="password" column="Password"/>
        <property name="emailAddress" column="EmailAddress"/>
        <set name="todoLists" table="userhaslist" lazy="false">
            <key column="UserID"/>
            <many-to-many column="ListID" class="com.brennydoogles.TodoList"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

List:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.brennydoogles.TodoList" table="list">
        <id name="listID" column="ListID"/>
        <property name="title" column="Title"/>
        <property name="description" column="Description"/>
        <set name="tasks" table="TASKINLIST" lazy="false">
            <key column="ListID"/>
            <many-to-many column="TaskID" class="com.brennydoogles.Task"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Task:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.brennydoogles.Task" table="task">
        <id name="taskID" column="TaskID"/>
        <property name="title" column="Title"/>
        <property name="description" column="Description"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This allows me to very simply grab a User (with all of their lists and tasks) or a List (with all of it's tasks). What I want to do now is find out a list of all users who have access to a particular list. I can't seem to figure out how to do it, and I am wondering if I may have some missing configuration for the linking tables.

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this (good hibernate tutorials might be nice as well)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with your entities set up the way they are.

Notice that `User` has a reference to one or more `TodoLists`, but `TodoList` doesn't have any property that maps back to a `User`. You need to define another property, and then you can do what you want.

Diagramatically, you have (where `-->` means "can access via a property"):

`User --> TodoList`

You want:

`User <--> TodoList`

The property mapping in `TodoList` would look something like this (sorry if it's not 100% accurate, I use annotations with Hibernate):

```
    <set name="usersWithAccess" table="userhaslist" lazy="false">
        <key column="ListId"/>
        <many-to-many column="UserId" class="com.brennydoogles.User"/>
    </set>
```